# Enabling Second Level cache on Eclipse link

Tags: weblogic, eclipselink

I need to port a JPA application which uses Hibernate as JPA Provider to Oracle WLS which uses EclipseLink JPA provider. As for the Hibernate, I needed some special configuration in persistence.xml to activate the second level cache. Is it activated by default with Eclipse Link ? I've found some outdated (2009) resources on the net which confirms it's on by default. Can anybody confirm it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is on by default.  See
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching
For details